# SMTP plain authentication problem using C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, smtp

Using MS Visual C++ and Boost asio, I'm trying to add the ability to send email to an application using the SMTP protocol.

The problem arises when I try to authenticate the connection. Here is a snapshot of the situation supposing the attempts to connect to an account in a server of the 1&1 provider, which uses its own server named "nemesis".

(**S**: server response and **C**: is the client-command) for test purposes, we assume that try to send a message from the account sender@mysite.com to target@mysite.com

```
C:    connect with hostname <smtp.1and1.es> and port <587> 
S:    220 smtp.1and1.es (mreu1) Welcome to Nemesis ESMTP server
C:    EHLO mysite.com
S:    250-smtp.1and1.es
S:    250-STARTTLS
S:    250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
S:    250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
S:    250-PIPELINING
S:    250-SIZE 120000000
S:    250 HELP
C:    AUTH LOGIN
S:    504 Unknown authentication mechanism
```

As far as I know, the server offers two authentication modes to the user: `LOGIN`  and `PLAIN`, and we try to use the former (the most used mode).

Supposedly, from this point, the server should answer with the requests of Username and Password. Some as:

```
S:    334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C:    avlsdkfj          <- Usename (base-64 encoded)
S:    334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C:    lkajsdfvlj        <- Password (base-64 encoded)
```

I've tried the command `auth login` (lower case) and `auth=login` without success.

I supposed that once obtained, the access the rest of the process is standard. Is to say some as:

```
C:    "MAIL FROM:<....>\r\n"
S:    250 .....
C    "RCPT TO:  ..\r\n"
S:    250 ...
C:    "DATA\r\n"
S:    354 ...
C:    bla, bla, bla        <-  message- body
C:    \r\n.\r\n
S:    250 ...
C:    "QUIT\r\n"
S:    221 ...
```

Comment: Can you paste some code? I tried this using 'telnet' and the 1&1 server sends the username prompt as expected.

Comment: telnet worked just fine for me as well.

Comment: @SimonJ @Luke. Thanks a lot for yours comments. That sound like some hope for my -I mean that as usual, the problem is in my side, and as result, surmountable-.  Unfortunately the actual code is quite complex, and no easily reproductible -the POP conection is already implemented successfully-. Let me rethink and recheck the whole think and come back as soon as I have some conclusion in that respect.

Any way, I would like to know if after de initial greeting of Nemesis, it can be used directly the AUTH LOGIN command exactly as stated in my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, sometimes the most obvious is the last hypothesis. In my problem, I was using a plain command

```
C: AUTH LOGIN
```

instead of

```
C: AUTH LOGIN\r\n
```

Note that you don't need append `\r\n` when using Telnet in Windows.

Be aware of use the same appendix when sending the encoded user-name and password.

By the way, besides the received comments, the page of Erwin Hoffmann [SMTP Authentication Tutorial](http://www.fehcom.de/qmail/smtpauth.html)  was a greath help to me.